# ¿Se puede mezclar Wordpress con HTML convencional?

Tags: html, wordpress

Me gusta hacer las landing pages escribiendo código HTML y CSS tradicionalmente, pero a la hora de hacer una tienda online es mucho mas fácil hacerla con Wordpress eCommerce. ¿Es posible poner solamente el eCommerce hecho en Wordpress en un subdominio (por ejemplo: sitioweb.com/shop) y que el resto sea html y css tradicional?

Comment: Sí, es posible.

Comment: Que seria el resto? si, se puede, porque wordpress es un "sistema" que en realidad es php y html... wordpress son un conjunto de funciones para darle una funcionalidad especifica a un sitio..

Comment: Te recomiendo que busques información de como crear Custom Themes - Temas Personalizados, si aprendes PHP, HTML, JS y el core de WordPress no tendras ningun  tipo de limitación. También te recomiendo leer [ask] ya que tu pregunta no se ajusta a las normas de la plataforma y puede terminar cerrada.